# House construction using concrete panels

Tags: concrete

**Background Information**

Currently looking to buy a house in the Southampton area in the UK and have noted there are quite a few houses which use a concrete panelling construction technique see example image below:

[image]

Some are advertised as Reema construction which can be difficult / impossible to obtain a mortgage on.  I have read up on Reema construction and this has currently put me off any type of concrete panel type buildings currently.

**The Questions**

What are the major pros and cons of concrete panelling construction, other than the obvious it's cheap and quick to build?

Is there a register in the UK to obtain information about the building type and construction which is accessible to the general public?

Thanks inadvance,
Suze

Comment: One way to filter out the problematical non-standard construction methods is the age of the property. Most of them were built in the first half of the 20th century, particularly during the rebuilding after WWII, and up to about 1960. There are also modern "environmentally friendly" non-standard building styles, but identifying them shouldn't be difficult. Any reputable estate agent should be up-front about the building style in their basic marketing information - they don't stand to gain anything from trying to sell you house where you can't get a mortgage if you need one, for example

Comment: … just contact some estate agents in the location you are interested in, and say you are only interested in conventional brick built houses. That should be enough to filter out the rest.